# CSS issues when trying to create a table of images

Tags: php, html, css

**Resolved: Desired outcome achieved** [image: Harambe bless us]

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a webpage that displays data pulled from a .txt via PHP in a table like format.

I've chopped and changed the code many times, just want the bloody images to continue onto a new row when they have reached the maximum page width...

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Template by html.am -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>2 Column Layout &mdash; Left Menu with Header &amp; Footer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dashboard/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div class="innertube">
                <h1>Header...</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <main>
                <div id="content">
                    <div class="innertube">
                        <h1>Heading</h1>
                        <?php
                        $contents = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
                        echo '<div class="row">';
                        foreach ($contents as $content)
                        {
                            echo '<div class = "column">';
                            if ($content == 'error')
                            {
                              echo '<img src="harambe.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">';
                              echo '<figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>';
                            }
                            else {
                                echo '<img src="Neo Tokyo 2098.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">';
                                echo '<figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>';
                            }
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                        echo '</div>';
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>

            <nav id="nav">
                <div class="innertube">
                    <h3>Left heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <h3>Left heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <h3>Left heading</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>  
        </div>

        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="innertube">
                <p>Footer...</p>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-family: Sans-Serif;
            line-height: 1.5em;
        }


        #header {
            background: #ccc;
            height: 100px;
        }

        #header h1 {
            margin: 0;
            padding-top: 15px;
        }

        main {
            padding-bottom: 10010px;
            margin-bottom: -10000px;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #nav {
            padding-bottom: 10010px;
            margin-bottom: -10000px;
            float: left;
            width: 230px;
            margin-left: -100%;
            background: #eee;
        }

        #footer {
            clear: left;
            width: 100%;
            background: #ccc;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 4px 0;
        }

        #wrapper {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #content {
            margin-left: 230px; /* Same as 'nav' width */
        }

        .innertube {
            margin: 15px; /* Padding for content */
            margin-top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .innertube img{
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
        .row{
            background-color: red;
            display:flex;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
    }
        .column{

        }
        .innertube figure{
            position: relative;

        }
        p {
            color: #555;
        }

        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav ul a {
            color: darkgreen;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3u9Q.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJiPK.jpg basic image of the website with the problem

I've tried to change the CSS, the HTML, adding div tags, removing div tags, chopping and changing code from questions across S.O, I don't think what I'm asking is unreasonable.

Comment: If you want a multiuline flexbox, you will need flex-wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css

```
.row {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.row:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.column {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    height: 120px;
}
.column figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Good thinking, I like where this is going however it positions them on a row per row basis, I'd like them to be say 10 on a row (or at maximum page length) then move onto the next row

Comment: sorry, I've forgotten to add some styles, please check updated version. I've added float, and updated .row:after, to omit content overlapping at the bottom of .row elements. It should 'jump' to the next line. No need to use different rows, you may use just one.

Comment: I added a little bit of padding to your answer, just to make sure the text is clear and well spaced out, thanks!!  

.column{
      position: relative;
      float:left;
      width:10%;
      height: 120px;
      padding: 10px;
   }